# HP ProBook 4720s - Fans running constantly at full

Tags: 10.10, acpi, fan

I was given a HP Probook 4720s as a work laptop, over the last 2 years I've predominantly used Ubuntu as my OS for work and home, but recently have needed to use Windows 7 as it controls the fans correctly.

I am now at the point where I want to try and resolve this issue. I haven't asked a question before for help as I can nearly always fulfill my queries with a search engine.

So here are the outputs from lspci/lsusb/lsmod not sure what is required so it's a starting point and also a link to the hardware from hardinfo.

[Hardinfo output](http://www.issathen.co.uk/hardware/4720s/hardinfo.html), [LSPCI Output](http://www.issathen.co.uk/hardware/4720s/lspci.txt), [LSUSB](http://%20www.Issathen.Co.Uk/hardware/4720s/lsusb.txt) and [LSMOD](http://%20www.Issathen.Co.Uk/hardware/4720s/lsmod.txt)

It has been suggested to me that Ubuntu one sync daemon could have been the issue but I've tried quitting this to no avail, I have also tried using the CPU Demand Frequency to it's lowest setting 933mhz but the fans *still* keep going.

`/proc/acpi/fan` is totally empty which I am guessing is that the fan hasn't been detected.

The sensors program detects temperatures but does not detect the speed of the fans.

```
andy@lappy:/proc/acpi/fan$ sensors
Acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
Temp1: +56.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)                  
Temp2: +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp3: +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp4: +38.0°C  (crit = +127.0°C)                  
Temp5: +0.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp6: +27.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp7: +64.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp8: +46.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp9: +51.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)                  
Temp10: +59.0°C  (crit = +128.0°C)    

andy@lappy:/proc/acpi/fan$ acpitool -f
Fan: not available
```

I'm guessing it's an ACPI issue but from lack of good results / Google foo I cannot find a solution.

I have tried a few fixes from the ubuntu forums which I am failing to find links for at the moment but none of them have been useful yet.

Just to add this happened from a clean install so no unruly processes as mentioned in other posts.

Open to try just about anything, I will reinstall if I need to.

Comment: As after James had fixed my hyperlinks issue I can't edit with out destroying the links I will add that I have also updated the BIOS to the newest version as well from the HP Site.

Comment: Any news on this issue? Are you happy with the Notebook under Ubuntu? I'm considering to buy one, so I would really appreciate your feedback! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked whether you use the proprietary ATI driver (flgrx package)? The open source radeon driver is known to have poor power management support.

Answer (score 0):

I found this:

http://quickfix1.blogspot.hu/2012/04/hp-probook-4530s-fan-noise-on-ubuntu.html

Try it for me (probook 4530s seems it fixed)

Comment: For the HP probook 4330s - which is similar - it doesn't.