# HP Probook 4530s fan constantly running

Tags: hp, fan

I have installed Ubuntu 11.10 successfully and everything works perfectly except the fan, it is working constantly and it has nothing to do with the CPU because if I don't open any programs it will remain at high speed.

I figured it may be because of AMD/ATI, I tried different ways of installing it manually and even automatically via Ubuntu itself but never worked!

Is there a (basic if possible) way of fixing this? Maybe controlling the fan speed would do the trick.

Comment: Installed any ATI drivers?

Comment: No I haven't been able to install it... I use Radeon HD 6490M and my Ubuntu is 64 bit. I tried to install it many times and had to reinstall Ubuntu after it was broken after installing the ATI config. Do you know a clear way to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Nice I just found http://www.uptechtalk.com/?p=86 on your website. I will try this and let you know ...

Comment: Your card is really not officially supported be ATI drivers in linux, I strongly recommend not doing it.

Comment: I already did and the Ubuntu became broken again, some errors appear on start-up and doesn't start the Ubuntu... does it mean my new laptop won't be working on Ubuntu at all? I am tired of using Win 7 ... do you recommend me to use other distributions ? Thanks again.

Comment: Its not that the Ubuntu does not support your card, its that the ATI drivers do not support it yet. To remove the ATI drivers and revert back to the open-source default drivers [check this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/74171/is-my-ati-graphics-card-supported-in-ubuntu).

Comment: Yeah I know that it is because of ATI... well I did what you said and it did revert it back but still sent some errors on black screen again, now I uninstalled it. Do you think there's a way to disable ATI so Ubuntu works properly? I really miss Ubuntu on this notebook!

Comment: http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Hardware/HP-ProBook-4530s-fan-constantly-running/td-p/1220567

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/33460/hp-probook-4720s-fans-running-constantly-at-full

Answer (score 1):

This is normal functioning for a laptop. Remember that the external temperature of the laptop is not necessarily a guide as to the temperature of the CPU, and naturally manufacturers are cautious when it comes to keeping the hardware cooled!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using VmWare ? 
If so you are using more of the RAM then normal, it will take 1GB to run the OS image then if your using Win 7 at lest 2GB will need to be working just to keep that running

So it could be the RAM thats going over drive

Comment: Thanks for your answer. No I have installed it via Wubi. I have  4GB RAM and my ATI is Radeon HD 6490M. Thoughts?

Comment: if your using a wubi boot loader. and running one OS at a time..    it could come down to Where is your laptop can it get air into it at all times ?

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Ubuntu 20.04 on this notebook with some upgrades like:

- now it has 4GB RAM total
- SSD 240GB

the fan goes up and down, so it looks that Ubuntu manages the fan but in the reality it doesn't go to minimum , neither while idle

When I have installed the SSD, 1 hour ago, I took the occasion to make a deep clean of the fan and the air circuit

I have the HDD with windows 7 and so I'm just testing ubuntu 20. So I have pretty sharp the fan speed when Windows 7 is idle:
it is hard to ear the fan

Please read carefully: just installed ubuntu 20 and I'm using Firefox to write in this question

Any idea or hint to make this usable, otherwise it is a pain earing the fan all the time

thank you